# P=NP giving a deterministic algorithm for SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, satisfiability, complexity-classes

I'm trying to prove the following problem:

> Prove that if $P=NP$ then there is a polynomial time algorithm for the following problem:
>
> **INPUT:** A boolean formula $\phi$. 
> **OUTPUT:** A satisfying assignment of $\phi$ if $\phi$ is satisfiable. If $\phi$ is unsatisfiable, return $false$.

#### My proof:

If $P=NP$ then $SAT$ can be decided in polynomial time. Run $SAT$ on $\phi$. If it returns $false$, reject. Else, nondeterministically select a boolean assignment. If it satisfies $\phi$, return it.

The algorithm is in $NP$, but because $P=NP$, it is also in $P$.

Is my proof correct? I'm asking because the textbook gave a different answer, and I want to know if my proof is correct, and if not, where does it fall?

Comment: > If it satisfies ϕ, return it. 
What do you do when it doesn't satisfy?

Comment: You have to use *self-reducibility* of SAT.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret The proposal is to use nondeterminism to select the satisfying assignment, not randomness. **NP** has nothing whatsoever to do with randomness.

Comment: @CurtisF The asker is proposing an algorithm that uses nondeterminism, and then trying to use **P=NP** to conclude that there is an equivalent deterministic one.

Comment: Which textbook and where is the answer?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the way you think, but there's a gap in your attempt.

$\mathrm{P}$ and $\mathrm{NP}$ are classes of decision problems, i.e., computational tasks where the answer is either "yes" or "no". Nondeterministically generating a satisfying assignment isn't a decision problem, so it isn't in $\mathrm{NP}$, so the assumption that $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$ doesn't give you a deterministic algorithm for it. It feels like it ought to, but that's not a proof.